# How to check if all multiple strings exist in another string (for all row in dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, substring

How can I check if all multiple strings existing in another string?

Then assign the result to a new column named "value".

Example of the dataframe:

| sub_strings | string | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ["the sun", "rising up"] | "the sun is rising up." | True |
| ["go home", "tomorow"] | "I will go home." | False |

My code is:

```
if all(x in df["string"] for x in df["sub_strings"]):
    df['value'] = True
else:
    df['value'] = False
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code snippet should do your work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'sub_strings': [["the sun", "rising up"], ["go home", "tomorow"]], 'string': ["the sun is rising up.", "I will go home."]})
df.head()
```

```
            sub_strings                 string
0  [the sun, rising up]  the sun is rising up.
1    [go home, tomorow]        I will go home.
```

```py
df['value'] = df.apply(lambda x: all([val in x.string for val in x.sub_strings]), axis=1)
df.head()
```

```
            sub_strings                 string  value
0  [the sun, rising up]  the sun is rising up.   True
1    [go home, tomorow]        I will go home.  False
```

Comment: Suppose you have a large dataset (1000+ ids), have you tested the speed?

Comment: @XxJames07- No I did not check the speed on 1000+ ids, need to create sample data for that. But I suppose Meeow(author) can further optimize the solution.